# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void newInstance(System.Location, System.Location) from the type System.Location

Tags: java, geolocation, salesforce

I'm trying to do a geolocation, but I keep having this error ~***Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void newInstance(System.Location, System.Location) from the type System.Location***~

Here's the code:

```
try{
        
        
        for(Lead_2__c ld : records){
            List<Double> distancias = new List<Double>();
            Map<Double,Id> mapDistUd = new Map<Double,Id>();

            for(Account ud : accs){                 
                Location locleads = Location.newInstance(ld.Latitude__c,ld.Longitude__c);
                Location locUD = Location.newInstance(ud.BillingLatitude,ud.BillingLongitude);
                Double dist = Location.getDistance(locleads, locUD, 'km');
                mapDistUd.put(dist, ud.Id);
                distancias.add(dist);
            }

            distancias.sort();
            System.debug('Unidade distribuidora mais próxima a ' + distancias.get(0) + ' Km');

            Id IdConta = mapDistUd.get(distancias.get(0));
            System.debug('Id da Unidade Distribuidora que será relacionada ao Lead: ' + IdConta);
            
            if(IdConta != null){
                ld.Conta__c = IdConta;
            }
        }
        
        update records;
    
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.debug('ERROR: ' + e.getMessage()+'. In line: ' + e.getLineNumber());
    }
}
```